HighPoint RocketRAID 2840C drivers for Ubuntu 24.04
Need help - how to install drivers to the subject?
HighPoint Data RAID-Linux Open Source Driver,
https://www.highpoint-tech.com/rr2800-overview
gives an error:
ERROR:Compile rr3740a for kernel 6.8.0-36-generic.
The driver may not support the above Linux kernel version. Please check the README file for confirmation.
ERROR:Not found Binary rr3740a for kernel 6.8.0-36-generic.


The error is very clear. Check the site of the HighPoint Data RAID-Linux Open Source Driver as to what kernels it works with.

Thank you very much for the prompt answer!
Unfortunately, there is only one Linux Open Source Driver at the site, and it looks like the installation script loads some data from the manufacturer's site for kernels up to 5.19, not higher.

So only for quite old version of Ubuntu.

Yes (not actually very old, Linux 5.19 released in mid 2022), I asked the support, they said that they plan to publish the upgrade by the end of this month. For me it will be OK.
